# Unable to load CSS files in Django

Tags: css, django, django-settings

I'm using Ubuntu and `Django 1.3.7`. Following are the various relevant settings:

My directory structure:

```
mysite/
      manage.py
      settings.py
      __init__.py
      urls.py
      myapp/
          __init__.py
          forms.py
          models.py
          views.py
          templates/
               index.html
               home.html
      static/
           common.css
           ...
           ...
```

My `settings.py` file:

```
import os.path
SETTINGS_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    ...
       'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    )
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SETTINGS_ROOT, "static/")
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my templates `html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Still, the pages don't show any images, css or js files. I've read the docs. But nothing helps. What else do I need to include/modify in order to get the files running?

Comment: Have you edited your URLconf correctly? Relevent docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Did your error got fixed? please share solution

Answer (score 0):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/path/to/your/project/assets',
)
```

Comment: Still not working. I added: `os.path.join(SETTINGS_ROOT, "static/"),`

Answer (score 0):

**settings.py**

```
import os
SETTINGS_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SETTINGS_ROOT, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(SETTINGS_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

main **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ................
) 

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**template**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

my static file configurions are below.

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
enter code herePER_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, os.path.pardir))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SUPER_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

it might help

Comment: and use it like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">